# navigation controller navigation bar only covers top left half of screen in plain vanilla code

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I'm just doing some ios programming after not touching it for a few months, and I'm new to it this year. I just started a new project, and all I did was programmatically set up a navigation controller as the root view controller.

Here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    nvc.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    nvc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    nvc.title = @"Woah";
//    nvc.navigationBarHidden = TRUE; this works ok

    self.window.rootViewController = nvc;

    return YES;
}
```

I don't have the reputation points to post an image, but here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbcqi.png

As you can see the title does not show in the navigation bar. Also, quite oddly, the navigation bar is only across the top left corner and not across the entire view. What am I missing here? Also if I set the commented out line to run, to hide the bar, that does work. But of course I want the bar, I don't not want it.

This is a brand new project I just started fresh, and I tried it in two new projects. I have the same outcome in both cases of this weird left corner bar. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the code without setting a view to the navigationController? Instead of addingViews to the navigationController, it does more sense to push a controller, as navigationControllers are containers to manage your app flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `UIViewController` as the root of you `UINavigationController`. At the moment you have no view controllers being managed.

The navigation bar title reflects the contents of each UIViewControllers UINavigationItem. By default the title on the navigation bar is the title of the UIViewController which is top most in the navigation stack.

The back button oddly reflects the title of the UINavigationItem of the UIViewController second from top. So to set the back button label you actually set it in the navigationItem of the controller which pushed the top controller on.

You can change the title by accessing the top view controllers navigationItem or from inside the top view controller using:

```
<a view controller>.navigationItem.title = @"My New Title";
```

or if from within the controller:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My New Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your intention to create UIWindow because it's the code for ages ago.

Now when you are upgrade your xCode to the latest version, there's no need to UIWindow to be created manually.

Also, when you are creating UINavigationController, it is much better when you are setting UINavigationController's rootView controller.

I am quite sure there will be UIViewController which need to be nested in UINavigationController.

So your code will need to be changed like below;

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController"]; //Let's assume this is the first VC on the navigation stack
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
//    nvc.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//    nvc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; use nvc.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
//    nvc.title = @"Woah"; use homeVC.title = @"Woah";
//    nvc.navigationBarHidden = TRUE; this works ok

self.window.rootViewController = nvc;
```